# Combining points into polygons with range of values using PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL table with a few million rows of [id, height, point] where the points are located in a ~100x100 grid.

I want to extract polygons from this data by combining points into polygons where the polygons contain a similar height. I want to be able to specify the height range (sometimes I might to have very many polygons and a narrow height interval and sometimes I might want to have fewer polygons and a wider height range)

How do I do this?

I tried to look though the functions in PostGIS but I couldn't find a suitable function.

Comment: I want to combine points that are close to each other that have a similar height, so yes,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`ST_ClusterDBSCAN`](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-dev/ST_ClusterDBSCAN.html) to cluster your points based on a height range, and [`ST_ConvexHull`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_ConvexHull.html) (or [`ST_ConcaveHull`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_ConcaveHull.html)) to create *Polygons*:

```
SELECT
  range_bin*<range> AS range_min,                  -- minimum bounds of range
  ST_ConvexHull(ST_Collect(geom)) AS geom
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      FLOOR(height::FLOAT/<range>::FLOAT) AS range_bin,
      ST_ClusterDBSCAN(point, <max_distance>, <min_points>) OVER(PARTITION BY FLOOR(height::FLOAT/<range>::FLOAT)) AS clst
      point AS geom
    FROM
      <your_table>
  ) q
GROUP BY
  range_bin, clst
;
```

Notes:

- the `eps` parameter (`<max_distance>` in the query) defines the maximum distance between points to get considered part of a cluster (refer to the docs and mabye follow the *Wikipedia* link for details about what this parameter *actually* implies); it is assumed to be in **units of CRS**, so for this to make most sense you will want to make sure your geometries are referenced in a suitable projection
- the `min_points` parameter determines the minimum amount of geometries needed to make up a cluster; note that this query may return all geometry types combined, e.g. if only a single *Point* is clustered, the result will be a *Point*; if two *Points* are clustered, the result will be a *LineString*; only with >= 3 *Points* (which you can define as condition with `<min_points> -> 3`) you will likely get only *Polygons* (but not guaranteed)
- the `FLOOR(height::FLOAT/<range>::FLOAT)` expression will  essentially create height range *bins* based on an acutal `<range>`, within which points can get assigned the same cluster; basically any expression works here, but this may make most sense

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I tried it but I couldn't really figure it out. I tried to use generate_series(1, 2000, 5) as <range>. (in your example is there a difference between `<range>` and `range_bin*<range>` ?), also the ST_ClusterDBSCAN is named `clst` in the subselect in your example but never used by the select statement or?

Comment: @axel_ande ah, forgot the `clst` in the `GROUP BY`, I updated the answer. Now, the `<range>` is supposed to be sth. like `2`, which means you'll get bins with height ranges `[0-2], [2-4], [4-6], ...`; but you can come up with any expression that groups heights into bins.

Comment: @axel_ande seeing your attempt with `Generate_Series` it looks like your intent there is to have a height range of `5`? Then simply use `5` as `<range>`. The difference is what the values express; `range_bin*<range>` will correspond to the actual height range lower bounds, while `range_bin` is the floored numerical result of the division - the *bin*.

Comment: @BERA generically, yes (`<geom>` is what I usually write) - but OP provided a column list with `point` being the only meaningful name for a geometry column...