# Combining points into polygons with range of values using ST_ClusterDBSCAN and ST_ConvexHull

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql, qgis-3

I tried to create polygons with similar depths based on values from point data.

I got some help to start with in this question [Combining points into polygons with range of values using PostGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/380078/combining-points-into-polygons-with-range-of-values-using-postgis)

Since the data points is in wgs84 (4326) I set the `max_distance` to 0.003 in `ST_ClusterDBSCAN(geom, 0.003 , 3)`. The problem is that I get many polygons that overlap each other, first I thought that this was a problem that could be solved by iterating over them and delete the overlap with `ST_Difference`. So I wrote a Python script and did this, but then I realized that it was both polygons with high and low depth values that overlapped.
[image]

Any idea how I can improve the generation of polygons from the data points or obtain a better result with the polygons that I got?

Comment: Is it possible you want contour lines instead of clusters?  If so, so this:  https://abelvm.github.io/sql/contour/

Answer (score 1):

Those *Polygon*s result from `ST_ClusterDBSCAN` assigning (and `ST_ConcaveHull` polygonizing) `NULL` values for rows where it couldn't find a suitable cluster; in that linked answer I suggested to use `min_points >= 3` to feed 3-*Point*-cluster collections to `ST_ConcaveHull` - but I failed to explain the consequences.

With `min_points >= 3` you will effectively dismiss any possible cluster with less than 3 *Point*s from your result, while keeping the initial *Point*s with `NULL` assigned (resulting in those large overlapping *Polygon*s); while you cannot create *Polygon*s from less than 3 *Point*s with `ST_ConcaveHull` (it will return *Point* or *LineString* geometries instead), it may yet be interesting to see their spatial correlation.

You have two options:

- since any row without suitable cluster affiliation will get `NULL` assigned, just don't feed those to `ST_Collect`:

  ```
  SELECT range_bin*<range> AS range_min,                  -- minimum bounds of  range
         ST_ConvexHull(ST_Collect(geom)) AS geom
  FROM   (
    SELECT FLOOR(height::FLOAT/<range>::FLOAT) AS range_bin,
           ST_ClusterDBSCAN(point, 0.003, 3) OVER(PARTITION BY FLOOR(height::FLOAT/<range>::FLOAT)) AS clst
           point AS geom
    FROM   <your_table>
  ) q
  WHERE  clst IS NOT NULL
  GROUP BY
         range_bin, clst
  ;
  ```

  This will only polygonize (and add to the result set) clusters with 3 or more affiliated *Points*; those without cluster assignment will get lost.
- let `ST_ClsuterDBSCAN` find clusters with `min_point = 1` (which will assign `clst` ids also to single *Point* clusters), and filter the resulting geometries by type (since most client software will not be able to work with multi-type sets):

  ```
  SELECT range_bin*<range> AS range_min,                  -- minimum bounds of  range
         ST_ConvexHull(ST_Collect(geom)) AS geom
  FROM   (
    SELECT FLOOR(height::FLOAT/<range>::FLOAT) AS range_bin,
           ST_ClusterDBSCAN(point, 0.003, 1) OVER(PARTITION BY FLOOR(height::FLOAT/<range>::FLOAT)) AS clst
           point AS geom
    FROM   <your_table>
  ) q
  GROUP BY
         range_bin, clst
  HAVING COUNT(geom) > 2 -- for Polygons; > 1 to include LineStrings; remove this (or > 0) to include Points
  ;
  ```

  or, to handle the edge cases where 3 *Point*s result in a *LineString* or some *Point*s have equal locations:

  ```
  SELECT *
  FROM   (
    SELECT range_bin*<range> AS range_min,                  -- minimum bounds of  range
           ST_ConvexHull(ST_Collect(geom)) AS geom
    FROM   (
      SELECT FLOOR(height::FLOAT/<range>::FLOAT) AS range_bin,
             ST_ClusterDBSCAN(point, 0.003, 1) OVER(PARTITION BY FLOOR(height::FLOAT/<range>::FLOAT)) AS clst
             point AS geom
      FROM   <your_table>
    ) q
    GROUP BY
           range_bin, clst
  ) q
  WHERE GeometryType(geom) = 'POLYGON'  -- 'POINT'/'LINESTRING'
  ;
  ```